# Calculate timedelta with loc?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a little bit of an issue with sth that should be fairly easy. My df looks as follows:

```
Index                 ZeitstempelSBA        Status1 counting
2018-01-02 12:20:00                         SR_OPEN    56
2018-01-02 12:21:00                         SR_OPEN    57
2018-01-02 12:22:00                         SR_OPEN    58
2018-01-02 12:23:00                         SR_OPEN    59
2018-01-02 12:24:00                         SR_OPEN    60
2018-01-02 12:25:00   2018-01-02 12:25:05   SR_CLEAR   0
2018-01-02 12:26:00                         SR_CLEAR   1
2018-01-02 12:27:00   2018-01-02 12:27:13   SR_CLOSE   0
2018-01-02 12:28:00                         SR_CLOSE   1
2018-01-02 12:29:00                         SR_CLOSE   2
2018-01-02 12:30:00                         SR_OPEN    0
2018-01-02 12:31:00                         SR_OPEN    1
2018-01-02 12:32:00                         SR_OPEN    2
2018-01-02 12:33:00                         SR_OPEN    3
2018-01-02 12:34:00                         SR_OPEN    4
2018-01-02 12:35:00   2018-01-02 12:35:11   SR_CLEAR   0
2018-01-02 12:36:00                         SR_CLEAR   1
2018-01-02 12:37:00   2018-01-02 12:37:17   SR_CLOSE   0
2018-01-02 12:38:00                         SR_CLOSE   1
2018-01-02 12:39:00                         SR_CLOSE   2
```

I'm trying to calculate the time difference between the first CLEAR and the first CLOSE interval across the entire dataframe. I tried using but it#s not ginving me the expected result:

```
begin = df.loc[(df.Status1 == 'SR_CLEAR')&(df.counting == 0),'ZeitstempelSBA']
end = df.loc[(df.Status1 == 'SR_CLOSE')&(df.counting == 0),'ZeitstempelSBA'] 
end-begin
```

Output should be an array/list of timedeltas between each SR_CLEAR (counting == 0) and SR_CLOSE (counting == 0) situation.

Comment: well your issue is simple, you don't have `SR-CLEAR` or `SR_CLOSE` in your dataframe, thus your booleans will never equate to true.

Comment: also, `df['counting']` never equals to 0 in the example, is that intentional?

Comment: Sorry, no. It wasn't intentional. I changed it....

Answer (score 0):

instead of using `.loc` you can just use `groupby.min` and `.to_dict()`

```
s = df[df['counting'].eq(0)].groupby("Status1")["ZeitstempelSBA"].min().to_dict()


print(s)

{'CLEAR': Timestamp('2018-01-02 12:25:05'),
 'CLOSE': Timestamp('2018-01-02 12:27:13')}

s['CLOSE'] - s['CLEAR'] 
Timedelta('0 days 00:02:08')
```

Comment: Thank you! It only works for one occurence though. The structure repeats in the dataframe though. I added some rows for clarification. I need the time dffierence between each CLEAR and CLOSE situation.....

Comment: @N.Foe can you add your intended output I edited output to include the counting logic.

Comment: I did now. The logic still gives only the timedelta between the first situation..?!

Comment: @N.Foe i don't understand - you _only_ have one value for each since you're filtering by `0` please see [ask] and [mcve]